# C++: Having troubles with do while loop

Tags: c++

```
do {
    cout << "Enter the account type (C for current and S for savings): ";
    cin >> account_type;
} while (account_type != 'S' || 'C');
```

I have  account_type set as char,the problem is that everytime i run the program and i input S or C the loop keeps repeating.Can anyone help me know why its happening?

Comment: `account_type != 'S' || 'C'` doesn't do what you think it does. Change that to `account_type != 'S' || account_type != 'C'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All non-zero values in c++ evaluate to `true` when used in a boolean operation. So `account_type != 'S' || 'C'` is the same as `account_type != 'S' || true`. Which means your loop never exits.

What you need to do is to preform both checks

```
do {
    cout << "Enter the account type (C for current and S for savings): ";
    cin >> account_type;
} while (account_type != 'S' && account_type != 'C');
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you cant say 'S' || 'C', you would think c++ would think that you mean if account_type is S or C however c++ looks at this in 2 separate sections: `(account_type == 'S') || ('C')`. ('C') will default to true therefore the loop loops forever.

What you need to write is:

```
do {
    cout << "Enter the account type (C for current and S for savings): ";
    cin >> account_type;
} while (account_type != 'S' && account_type != 'C');
```

You need to change the || to && because if account_type is S then it cant be C and the same vice versa therefore the loop never finishes.

Comment: So && will act like || does for integers?

Comment: @Akula the reason I changed it to && is because the code will still loop indefinetly with ||. Both && and || work on integers except && means 'and' and || means 'or'

Comment: @Akula when you use || and && on numbers the number gets turned into a boolean. If it isn't 0 it gets turned into true and if its 0 it gets turned to false.

Answer (score 0):

Your while check is wrong. You have to write it like this:

`while (account_type != 'S' || account_type != 'C')`

You can't perform `||` checks, or any for that matter like that, you must always re-state the variable.